# Find Partial NAME tag Selenium Java

Tags: selenium, find, partial

HTML

```
<button id="SearchCriteria_20">
```

The problem is the "_20" part of the ID is auto generated each time the page is loaded; how would you be able to fine the partial (static bit) of SearchCriteria%?

Thanks all....

Comment: Do you want to find all buttons which have partial text - SearchCriteria ?

Comment: Just the one; but turns out there is actually two buttons that use the same static wording :S.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'SearchCriteria')]")).click

Comment: does that _20 id changes everytime?

Comment: Yeah, on each page load - dont ask me why....

Comment: So tried with xpath and that seems to do the trick.....

Comment: then you will have to do like this  `List<WebElement> button = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'SearchCriteria')]")); button.size(); button.get(1).click();` so it will click on first button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you have 2 buttons that fit "SearchCriteria"

using the following xpath-expressions:

```
//button[contains(@id, 'SearchCriteria')][1]
```

for the first button or

```
//button[contains(@id, 'SearchCriteria')][2]
```

for the second button

Comment: it will find 2 buttons , right? as OP says 2 button has same partial text.